# Export bwip.js (with angular-wrapper) barcode as png

Tags: javascript, angularjs, barcode

I am using [td-angular-barcode](https://github.com/tinydesk/td-angular-barcode), an angular wrapper for bwip.js to generate a barcode on my website. I now need to make this barcode available for download (.png prefered). Is it possible to access just the barcode/canvas?
Currently the html element looks like this:

```
<td-barcode config="config"></td-barcode>
```